# Unable to draw text on the desktop screen beneath the icons on the top of wallpaper

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, text, desktop

I'm new to linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and I want to draw text on the top of desktop wallpaper in Ubuntu beneath all the icons.
Earlier, I did it on win32 like this :

```
desk = GetDesktopWindow();
dc = GetDC(desk);
MoveToEx(dc,0,0,NULL);
LineTo(dc,1680,1050);
ReleaseDC(desk,dc);
```

It rendered the text on the top of all the windows but I wanted the text to be displayed on the desktop only no matter how many windows are currently open wide. Later, I found the solution using Spy++.
Now I googled a lot but didn't find a solution for Ubuntu/linux. I'm using C/C++.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Also, I recommend using Qt. Using it is more pleasant experience.

Comment: In both cases you are doing it the wrong way. Getting the current desktop context only allows you to make transient changes to the display. If you want to modify the wallpaper, you'll need to create a modified wallpaper (image file) and then tell the WM to use your modified image.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I don't want to modify the wallpaper at all. Just want to add a layer in between the wallpaper and the icons

Comment: No such layer exists.

Comment: You might consider creating a transparent window that you sink to the bottom of the z-stack.